# Power Automate can not connect to On-Premises Data Gateway

Tags: power-automate

I built a PoC UIFlow and want to trigger it from Power Virtual Agents. 
So I built a new Power Automate Flow which starts a UiFlow, but the UiFlow somehow can not connect to the datagateway and I always get this error:

`AgentConnectionVersionOutdated`

Any ideas how I can fix it?

I am using my university account for all the steps (on the datagateway, in the UiFlow connection and in Power Automate/Airtual Agents)

Answer (score 0):

For Uiflow to identify the gateway,  both the environment region and the gateway region should be same . You should be able to find gateway under the Data tab on the left panel of power automate . If your gateway is not listed there then try reconfiguring the region of your on-premises gateway . You cn find the environments region by going into the admin centre and clicking the  environment you work on .